# Wrong bookmarks with hypdoc

Tags: glossaries, bookmarks, doc

The following MWE points out that, with `hypdoc` package, the bookmark of the change history section is wrong: "Change History" instead of "Other title for change history".

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{doc}\usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypdoc}
\RecordChanges
\GlossaryPrologue{%
  \section{Other title for change history}
}%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\changes{v1}{2016/09/30}{Initial version}
\PrintChanges
\end{document}
```

The trouble doesn't arise with `doc`+`hyperref` packages.

### Update

This issue is much more troublesome for e.g. the list of figures and the list of tables, the bookmarks of which being "Contents" with `hypdoc`:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{doc}\usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypdoc}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\section{Foo}
\end{document}
```

Do you see what's going on?

Comment: It is in fact enough to load `hypdoc` with its `numbered` option but that 's an unsatisfactory workaround as one could not want get numbered these usually unnumbered sections.

Comment: The bug is identified: Copy and paste error in `hypdoc`. It uses `\contentsname` instead of `\listfigurename` and `\listtablename` in the bookmarks for `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`. (Option `numbered` uses a different code.)